# Numpy Finding complex conjugate

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a way to compute for the complex conjugate, given an array with complex elements?

I have an array consisting of imaginary elements using fast Fourier transform (fft.fft) and would like to return a list with the complex conjugate of each element.

I was thinking of extracting the imaginary bits by using nparray.imag, but it creates a list without "j" to denote imaginary.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is there no `conjugate()` method as there is for `complex`?

Comment: There is. `np.conjugate(a)` where `a` is an array does work.

Comment: How did you get stuck?  A simple browser search on "numpy complex conjugate" brought several direct hits on the first page.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a numpy array of complex numbers, `arr`, you can use:

```
arr.conj()
```

to create an array consisting of the conjugates of `arr`.  You can also use `arr.conjugate()`, which is a synonym.